# fatal error C1189: #error : Windows SDK version error

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-7-x64

I got a project from my friend and when I try to build it I'm getting following error.

fatal error C1189: #error :  Your version of the Windows SDK is earlier than 6.0. Try setting the 'WINVER' and '_WIN32_WINNT' definitions in your project to less than 0x0600.

Using VS2008 on Windows 7 x64

Please help to overcome from this error.

Comment: That sounds like a very descriptive error message - so what is your problem?

Comment: Search for those two macros on MSDN and one of the [top hits might be informative.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I added #define WINVER 0x0601 & #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 to stdafx.h. But still error is there.

Comment: @Nadsa It says `Try setting ... less than 0x0600`. Why would you set them higher and wonder why the error is still there?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I tried. But after that hundreds of errors occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this error is that the version of the Windows SDK built into your VS2008 environment is older than the project you're trying to build. It isn't supposed to work.

What do do? It is unlikely (but not impossible) that editing something somewhere will fix it. I wouldn't do that.

You could update your VS to a later version. That would be the best solution.

You could recreate the project supplied by your friend by transferring the files to a new project created on your VS2008.

Comment: VS2010 installed.. Working with it.. But there should be an answer..Anyway thanks..